# Except Handling for Requests HEAD

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am intentionally checking a BAD url: https://google55.com in order to see how the error will be handled.

I do have some `except`s, however they don't seem to be doing anything.

```
h = {
    'Server': server, 
    'User-Agent': server + ' (Node 01)', 
}
try:
    resp = requests.head("https://google55.com", headers=h) 
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print ('Timeout...')
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    print ('Bad URL...')
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
```

Because I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google55.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xffff99595978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 316, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xffff99595978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google55.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xffff99595978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "uptime_test1.py", line 12, in <module>
resp = requests.head("https://google55.com", headers=h)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 101, in head
return request('head', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google55.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xffff99595978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "uptime_test1.py", line 28, in <module>
sys.exit(1)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# 
root@gateway:/var/www/default/python/uptime# python3 uptime_test1.py 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google55.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xffff89210978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
Status
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "uptime_test1.py", line 31, in <module>
print (resp.status_code)
NameError: name 'resp' is not defined
```

Need to somehow catch this error, in order for the script to know that it is a bad URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the related part of your code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "uptime_test1.py", line 31, in <module>
print (resp.status_code)
NameError: name 'resp' is not defined
```

It is a `NameError` exception. Your `resp` variable is not defined which is in `File "uptime_test1.py", line 31, in <module>`. Probably, you want to set this variable in an `if` branch and your code doesn't run into this `if`.

But if you want to handle this exception, you can try:

```
try:
    print (resp.status_code)
except NameError:
    print("Undefined variable")
```

**Note:** If you check the traceback, you can see more `requests.exceptions.X` and `urllib3.exceptions.X` exceptions which are not handled in your code.

Comment: `resp` is not defined because `requests.head("https://google55.com", headers=h)` fails!

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the right exceptions, you can check in the stack trace for the exceptions that are actually raised, and catch them instead. Some exceptions in the trace:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
NameError
# ... none of which you're handling
```

Even though `requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects` and `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError` my seem to have the same cause, the exceptions themselves are not the same.

Comment: But I am not using `urllib3`?